# wireless ethernet adapter with EAP-PEAP?

Tags: wifi, ethernet, bridge, peap

We have a wireless network set up to support WPA or WPA2 with AES or TKIP encryption and EAP-PEAP authentication.  Users are wanting to connect devices that don't have the ability to do EAP-PEAP but have ethernet ports.  I have found a [wireless printer server](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/us/en/en/WF06b/18972-18972-236253-34210-396578-3980754-3980826-3980828.html) that can do this, but I have yet to find a wireless ethernet adapter that can.  Has anyone seen one with this ability?

Answer (score 1):

I seemed to have found some that can do what I want according to the specs, but I can't confirm them in real world use.

- [Silex SX-BR-4600WAN](http://www.silexamerica.com/products/connectivity-solutions/wireless-infrastructure/ethernet-to-wi-fi-bridges/sx-br-4600wan/)
- [HP 501 Wireless Client Bridge
  (J9835A)](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/networking-wireless/product-detail.html?oid=6372587)

Answer (score 0):

The [HP Procurve 210 wireless bridge](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/uk/en/sm/WF05a/12883-12883-1137927-3445283-3445283-1847675.html) should do what you want.

Edit: There are also the 220 & 230 models in the same range.

Also many home/small business broadband wireless routers have a bridge/repeater mode.

Comment: I haven't found any documentation showing that the Procurve 210, 220, or 230 work as a bridge.